# Is it possible to only accept specific value of a route parameter using route attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

The following code does what I want to do. If the string parameter `ForSaleOrRent` has any value but `ForSale` or `ForRent` the action method returns `HttpNotFoundResult`. My question is this doable using only Route attribute?

```
[Route("post/{ForSaleOrRent}")]
public ActionResult PostProperty(string ForSaleOrRent)
{
    bool IsValidUrl = ForSaleOrRent.ToUpper() == "FORSALE" || 
                      ForSaleOrRent.ToUpper() == "FORRENT";
    if (!IsValidUrl)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }
    return View(ForSaleOrRent);
}
```

Comment: Would not using 2 distinct functions mapping specific address solve your problem?

Comment: @Phil1970 the above code works as well but I would like to know if this can be done using the route attribute.

Comment: Why not use an `enum` in the first place?

Comment: @haim770 you're a genius.

Comment: @haim770 I just tested it with enum but it accepts integers as well as forsale and forrent

Comment: @AmitHasan, Generally in MVC, model-validation is being done as part of the model-dinding process. So, if you'll write a custom model-binder for your `enum` type, you'll be able to mark it as invalid for any value that doesn't match `FORSALE` or `FORRENT` (for example). If you feel like this is the way to go, I'll write an answer with the code.

Comment: @haim770 Thank you very much for the information. I didn't knew that before. I will look into that soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an inline constraint

```
[Route("post/{ForSaleOrRent:regex(^forrent$|^forsale$)}")]
public ActionResult PostProperty(string ForSaleOrRent)
{
    return View(ForSaleOrRent);
}
```

References:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-2-attribute-routing-with-custom-constraints
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: Would that give me the value of ForSaleOrRent?

Comment: I just tested it and it shows error- "The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'values(forrent|forsale)'."

Comment: I wasn't quite sure about that. It said in the post "Attribute routing previously offered custom inline constraints, like this", but didn't give any indication how they were changed. I found the 2nd link above, and corrected the constraint. Alternatively, you can use the `ValuesConstraint` from the 2nd link (see the Custom Route Constraints section).

Comment: how to also ignore case ?